# Подключение отдельной части вида (view)

Tags: php, laravel

Использую Laravel 5.

Имеется шаблон, который подгружается файлом отображения (view).
Чтобы не дублировать шапку сайта, к примеру "меню", я хочу использовать его повторно, но в шапке должны быть данные авторизованного пользователя.

Еще в шапке имеется меню, которое будет меняться в зависимости от роли пользователя.

Как я могу это организовать? Внедрить в layout типа?!

Comment: так а что не получается? это тривиальная задача которая описана в официальной документации

Comment: Я не  хочу инклудить просто файл _nameview.blade.php

Comment: Хочу инклудить файл который будет обрабатывать модель и выводить во view. И этот так сказать модуль уже инклудить в шаблон. Как так сделать ?

Comment: Дело в том что меню пользователя будет динамически меняться в зависимости от роли пользователя. По этому существует некая логика(фильтрация). И это все хочу проводить как модуль, а уже именно его коннектить к шаблону layout